# Drag and Drop Sorting App in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, drag-and-drop

I really need your guidance in creating Drag and Drop sorting App using Angularjs.

Now, my app receives, `json` with wall posts data, from one of social networks via it's API.

I use ng-repeat to form some kind of a card-item representing wall post. Also use `ngInfiniteScroll` to load posts.

After this preparational work, it's time for me to start working on the main functionality, which is sorting post. And here's where I got totally confused.

The way of sorting posts should be next:

Drag the item (wall post card) on the pre fixed area, some kind of a folder (actually a link to another html page). After dropping it in to this area the post should disappear from the main page and be displayed on another page.

I'm thinking to use ng-hide for displaying sorted posts.

**How can I create a class for my sorted wall post card after dropping it in drop-area?**

[Here](https://github.com/vinnyzepooh/AppWS)'s my project.
Just give me a direction or may be there's some analog of it has been already created elsewhere.